# Measuring 10 volts?

Tags: gpio, power

I am building a movement monitoring system on a Raspberry Pi 2. I've just put a meter on the 5V and GND pins, and I'm measuring ~10V. The 3V3 and GND show 7.5V.

What on earth is going on? Or have I got this wrong somehow?

BTW - Windows 10 IoT is running OK on the Pi.

Comment: If those voltages hit any of those pins, your Pi would likely release the [magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke). If it hasn't, there's something amiss with your metering arrangement.

Comment: What are you using to measure the voltage with, a standard multimeter? It could one of many reasons that you are getting twice the expected reading. As a sanity check - maybe your meter badly needs calibrating (do you have a reference with which to check it?), or the input impedance of the meter is too low (see [Why does an oscilloscope show a different voltage from a signal generator?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117806/why-does-an-oscilloscope-show-a-different-voltage-from-a-signal-generator)), or you have the leads plugged in to the current measuring socket?

Comment: Your meter needs a new battery, or you have killed the Pi.  What is the rating of your power supply?

Comment: Ah - a 9V battery is reading as 11.7V. My meter seems chuffed.

Comment: The leads are in the correct sockets, and it's on the correct setting - but it seems far from correct. That will teach me just to trust it blindly.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

A new battery in the multimeter has fixed the problem. I never knew a low battery would affect it's readings - I assumed if it switched on, it was good to go.

With the new battery it's reading 8.7V for a fresh 9V battery. Still not super-accurate (time for a new one I think), but at least it shows my Pi is OK.

Thanks for the help everyone.
(I would mark someone's answer as correct, but they are all comments.)

Comment: [Once you hit 15 rep you can mark your own answer as the accepted one](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). New battery's better than a new Pi!